# VM Depot SourceImageName using Azure REST API

Tags: api, rest, azure

I'm using the **Create Virtual Machine Deployment** method of the Azure REST API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157194.aspx

I'm trying to use an image sourced from the VM Depot, with a path such as this:

```
http://vmdepotwestus.blob.core.windows.net/linux-community-store/community-4-d803ca0a-5d98-4be8-8895-2a9d15ec3974-1.vhd
```

I am currently getting the following error:

> The virtual machine image source is not valid.

I am assuming there is some process which first needs to be completed in order to make that image available to the specific API user, but I can't seem to work out what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't deploy directly from VM Depot. You must first copy the image to your own storage account. There are instructions on the VM Depot help page for doing this via the Azure Management portal (see http://vmdepot.msopentech.com/Help/Help.cshtml#deployingUsingAUX). It can also be done via the CLI tools, see http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/install-and-configure-cli/#use

Answer (score 0):

It is more complicated. You have to download the VHD from some link in VM Depot in your storage, create the image, then provision the machine.

The command line of VMdepot to do that is in node, so you can very easily reverse it to see how it works.

On the other hand, I do it also with [IaaS Management Studio](http://iaas.ao-is.com/), you might be able to take a look with reflector how I did.